# Bulk load AWS S3 to Postgres streaming STDIN

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

The goal is to load a csv in an s3 bucket to a table in postgres in RDS. Looking for "best practices" I found AWS recommends their "Data Pipeline" product. They give you a starter template for bulk load csv to rds mysql. The template looks like the screenshot below. My reaction is "wow - all this boxes and arrows just to load a csv to a table?"

[image: data pipeline]

So my question is "Can we find a simpler approach to the same goal?". Assume my bucket, my database and a free-tier T2.micro EC2 instance reside in the same region. Assume AWS CLI and postgres client are installed on the EC2.

I can run the following command which reads the CSV from the bucket to stdout and pipes the stream to the postgres bulk load command:

`aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/dummy.csv - | psql -d mydb -p 5432 -c "copy dummy(f1, f2) from stdin with(format csv);"`

^^^ This works for 50MB files! It doesnt seem to require a significant buffer of memory. It does not display progress. Will this approach work for very large files 10GB? 100GB? etc? Is this robust or do I really need to use the data pipeline product?

Comment: FWIW, have uploaded 300MB files into RedShift from S3 in similar fashion. Would be interested to know if there is a limit, though.

Comment: @StuartLC redshift has native support for s3 via COPY command. This works well for terabytes of flat files. Postgres RDS does not have native support for s3 which is why I am piping from STDIN

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using DMS for this design with S3 as a source and postgres as the target. The DMS SHOULD be cli-scripted to make the process repeatable and on-demand which can be involved however if you have a once-in-a-while need for data loading then the script pays off in terms of getting consistent results from a portable utility